# Checkbox inside tab toggle bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create tabs with the functionality to add checkbox as well but with the present of `data-toggle="tabs"`, checkbox doesn't seem to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/moviecrew/gdpvuh4r/2/ here is my fiddle.

Is there any way we can make the checkbox work when it's inside tab toggle?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

`data-togle="tab"` click event has a `preventDefault()` inside `bootstrap.js` and as your `checkbox` is inside `a[data-toggle="tab"]` when you click on it you are actually clicking on `<a>` and the click event are being prevented by bootstrap.

If you still want to have it inside a `data-toggle="tab"` you'll need some additional javascript logic to check/uncheck it manually, something like this:

```
$('[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function() {
    var isChecked = $(this).find(':checkbox').prop('checked');
    $(this).find(':checkbox').prop('checked', !isChecked);
})
```

Comment: No, the checkbox/switch has different function. It’s hard to explain but it should work separately to tabs. It just need to be there. Also, the problem is not because the checkbox is inside `<a>` tag, even if you use div, you’ll see the same problem. The actual problem is with data-toggle, try removing it, and checkbox works fine.

Comment: @Lucian it works without data-toggle because very probably inside bootstrap.js there's an event to preventDefault the click on it which causes your checkbox not being checked because it's inside a <a> tag that's having it's default click behavior being prevented. As I said you'll need to add some javascript logic to check/uncheck it manually.